# Haskell "abc123de45" to [123,45]

Tags: string, haskell, int

From a String like "abc123def45" i want to get -> [123, 45].

I have the following now:

```
getDecimals :: String -> [Int]
getDecimals xs = [ digitToInt x | x<-xs , isDigit x]
```

Only this method is returning -> [1,2,3,4,5].

How can i do this?

Tnx!

Comment: Take a look at the function `Data.List.groupBy`.

Comment: Hint: you can split when alpha and filter not null elements

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `Data.List.Split` you can do this.

```
import Data.List.Split
import Data.Char

getDecimals :: String -> [Int]
getDecimals = map read . wordsBy (not . isDigit)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (quite long) on-liner to do this:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

getDecimals = ((map (read::String->Int)).(filter (isNumber.head)).(groupBy (\a b -> (isNumber a) && (isNumber b))))
```

Now let's break it down:

```
(
    ( map (read::String->Int) ).    -- Go over the list of numerical strings and read them as Ints
    ( filter (isNumber.head) ). -- Filter out the strings which are not begining with digit
    ( groupBy           -- Split the given list based on the following comparison function:
        (\a b -> (isNumber a) && (isNumber b)) -- The comparison function to return true if both arguments are digits
    ) 
)
```

Since we are using the `.` function, which is function composition, the functions above are applied in the order bottom to top to the given argument list. I am pretty sure there is more elegant ways to do this, but I can't think of any at this moment.

Comment: Tnx a lot! I needed the ( map (read::String->Int) ) part.

solved it like this: getDecimals xs = ((map (read::String->Int)) ( filter (not . null) (splitOneOf ['A'..'z'] xs) ))

Dont't know if it is the best way, but it works:)

Comment: unconventional parentheses. I think it's more cleaner without. also beware that your `getDecimals` is partial.

Answer (score 0):

I've never played with [regex-applicative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative) before, so I guess I'll give it a go!

NOTE: the cleanest version, but the least interesting, is way down at the bottom.

The first version here is written to use just one regular expression, which means it's not at all lazy (oy!).

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Data.Char

fakeDigitToInt :: Char -> Int
fakeDigitToInt x = ord x - ord '0'

digit = fakeDigitToInt <$> psym isDigit

addDigit big small = 10*big+small

number = addDigit <$> reFoldl Greedy addDigit 0 digit <*> digit

spacers = many (psym $ not . isDigit)

numbersInCrud = many (spacers *> number) <* spacers

readNumbersFromCrud = maybe [] id . match numbersInCrud
```

To make a lazy version, it's necessary to break things up a bit more, using more features of the parsing system. While I'm at it, I'll fix up the types a bit:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Data.List (unfoldr)

fakeDigitToInt :: Char -> Int
fakeDigitToInt x = ord x - ord '0'

digit :: Num n => RE Char n
digit = fromIntegral . fakeDigitToInt <$> psym isDigit

addDigit big small = 10*big+small

number :: Num n => RE Char n
number = addDigit <$> reFoldl Greedy addDigit 0 digit <*> digit

spacers = many (psym $ not . isDigit)

pullNumber :: Num n => String -> Maybe (n, String)
pullNumber = findLongestPrefix (spacers *> number)

readNumbersFromCrud :: Num n => String -> [n]
readNumbersFromCrud = unfoldr pullNumber
```

#### The cleanest version

This is kind of boring, but it is simple:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Text.Regex.Applicative.Common
import Data.Char
import Data.List (unfoldr)

spacers = many (psym $ not . isDigit)

pullNumber :: Num n => String -> Maybe (n, String)
pullNumber = findLongestPrefix (spacers *> decimal)

readNumbersFromCrud :: Num n => String -> [n]
readNumbersFromCrud = unfoldr pullNumber
```

And because I couldn't resist, here's the (almost) one-liner:

```
import Text.Regex.Applicative
import Text.Regex.Applicative.Common
import Data.Char
import Data.List (unfoldr)

readNumbersFromCrud :: Num n => String -> [n]
readNumbersFromCrud = unfoldr . findLongestPrefix $
  many (psym $ not . isDigit) *> decimal
```